# Set ODBC data source file for MS Access Driver with a script (Powershell, batch...) on Windows

Tags: powershell, odbc

I need to change my ODBC data source MS Access file frequently during debugging.

Manually, the step is to open ODBC Data Sources, select the (existing) DSN, configure, select the .mdb file on disk. Close.

I'd like to do this via a script (Powershell, Batch, ...) where i'd provide the DSN and file path on the command line.
What options do i have to set the ODBC data source from Powershell for example?

Comment: I recommend checking out the command `Set-OdbcDsn`, [Set-OdbcDsn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/set-odbcdsn?view=win10-ps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved using **Set-OdbcDsn**.

```
$DbqProperty = "DBQ=$ResolvedDatabasePath"
Set-OdbcDsn -Name $DsnName -DsnType "System" -Platform "64-bit" -SetPropertyValue "$DbqProperty"

(Get-OdbcDsn -Name DEBUG_MDB).Attribute.DBQ
```